# Managing Environment variables ejabberd server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Is there any way to manage multiple environment variables (dev/stage/production) from single ejabberd server.
Specifically different database for each environment. e.g

```
development
----------- 
db : devdb
user : user
pass : pass 

stage
-----
db : stagedb
user : user
pass : pass 

production
---------- 
db : proddb
user : user
pass : pass
```

> Ubuntu 16.04  Ejabberd 17.xx Database : mysql client :
>   react-native(android/ios)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have configured in ejabberd several vhosts, and you want to use a different SQL database for each one. For defining each database in ejabberd.yml, you can use the host_config option, see https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#virtual-hosting

Comment: Thanks, buddy it works! Found some other features also during this reading.